# Is there a gas cost incurred when creating a contract abstraction?

Tags: contract-development, gas, vyper

I have a smart contract in vyper (`SomeContract`) that gets called within another smart contract:

```
some_contract: address = _some_contract
SomeContract(some_contract).foo() # Is there a cost incurred here with SomeContract()?
SomeContract(some_contract).foo()
```

vs

```
some_contract: SomeContract = SomeContract(_some_contract)
some_contract.foo()
some_contract.foo()
```

Does using `SomeContract(some_contract)` to obtain an abstraction cost gas?

Which of the two versions is cheaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the expression `SomeContract(some_contract)` is resolved during compilation time.

It has no runtime impact whatsoever (gas cost or other).